# Is there a vectorized way of removing all transactions but the most recent N for each customer ID?

Tags: r, subset

I have a transactions sample - customer `ID`, transaction `DATE`, transaction `VALUE` (one transaction per day at most) ... all sorted by `ID` then by `DATE`.

I need to keep only the most recent `N` transactions for each customer (say 3 latest). Is there a vectorized way to do that? In the original sample I have millions of transactions - FOR loops take too long to execute.

```
ID  DATE    VALUE
205 18.10.2010  19
209 30.09.2010  19
209 21.10.2010  19
209 07.11.2010  19
228 08.11.2010  159
237 24.10.2010  159
237 13.11.2010  200
248 30.09.2010  25
274 05.10.2010  19
274 11.10.2010  10
274 25.10.2010  19
274 05.11.2010  19
292 25.09.2010  159
292 03.10.2010  159
292 10.10.2010  159
292 26.10.2010  159
292 07.11.2010  159
310 18.10.2010  19
310 07.11.2010  19
310 19.11.2010  19
354 23.10.2010  19
354 02.11.2010  19
354 14.11.2010  19
354 22.11.2010  19
368 18.10.2010  19
369 25.09.2010  25
369 26.09.2010  25
369 27.09.2010  25
369 02.10.2010  25
369 04.10.2010  159
369 11.10.2010  20
369 15.10.2010  10
369 16.10.2010  19
369 23.10.2010  10
369 26.10.2010  10
369 29.10.2010  10
369 01.11.2010  10
369 02.11.2010  30
369 08.11.2010  10
369 13.11.2010  20
369 15.11.2010  70
369 23.11.2010  20
375 14.11.2010  159
382 11.10.2010  18
382 16.11.2010  20
387 26.10.2010  19
407 26.09.2010  25
407 04.10.2010  25
407 10.10.2010  70
407 25.10.2010  19
```

Comment: Do you even have your data in R yet?  This is the most frequently asked question in the [r] tag.  What have you tried?

Comment: Posting `dput(mydata)` (or whatever your data frame is) would make this question reproducible and easier to answer.

Comment: The above sample in fact IS my data frame. 50 rows out of ~5 millions.

Comment: @dmitryungurean. Ah, but you didn't tell us it was a `data.frame`.  Knowing what you're working with is the first step to getting a solution.

Comment: sorry for that. i'm rather new here:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a lot of data and speed is an issue, you should use the [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) package

If your `data.frame` is in an object called `dat`, coerce it to a `data.table` like this

```
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
```

Since the current format of your `DATE` column is not easily sortable, let's first create a new column that has actual Dates.  In the `data.table` package, the `:=` is an assignment by reference operator.

```
DT[, DATE2:=as.Date(DATE, "%d.%m.%Y")]
```

Now we have a new column called `DATE2` with Dates.  We can `order` by date, then split by
`ID` and get the last 3 values (`tail(.SD, 3)`).  `.SD` stands for "Subset of Data" in the data.table package

```
> DT[order(DATE2), tail(.SD, 3), by=ID]
     ID       DATE VALUE      DATE2
 1: 292 10.10.2010   159 2010-10-10
 2: 292 26.10.2010   159 2010-10-26
 3: 292 07.11.2010   159 2010-11-07
 4: 369 13.11.2010    20 2010-11-13
 5: 369 15.11.2010    70 2010-11-15
 6: 369 23.11.2010    20 2010-11-23
 7: 407 04.10.2010    25 2010-10-04
 8: 407 10.10.2010    70 2010-10-10
 9: 407 25.10.2010    19 2010-10-25
10: 209 30.09.2010    19 2010-09-30
11: 209 21.10.2010    19 2010-10-21
12: 209 07.11.2010    19 2010-11-07
13: 248 30.09.2010    25 2010-09-30
14: 274 11.10.2010    10 2010-10-11
15: 274 25.10.2010    19 2010-10-25
16: 274 05.11.2010    19 2010-11-05
17: 382 11.10.2010    18 2010-10-11
18: 382 16.11.2010    20 2010-11-16
19: 205 18.10.2010    19 2010-10-18
20: 310 18.10.2010    19 2010-10-18
21: 310 07.11.2010    19 2010-11-07
22: 310 19.11.2010    19 2010-11-19
23: 368 18.10.2010    19 2010-10-18
24: 354 02.11.2010    19 2010-11-02
25: 354 14.11.2010    19 2010-11-14
26: 354 22.11.2010    19 2010-11-22
27: 237 24.10.2010   159 2010-10-24
28: 237 13.11.2010   200 2010-11-13
29: 387 26.10.2010    19 2010-10-26
30: 228 08.11.2010   159 2010-11-08
31: 375 14.11.2010   159 2010-11-14
     ID       DATE VALUE      DATE2
```

Alternatively, you can set a `key`

This would be equivalent, but maybe faster

```
setkey(DT, DATE2, ID)
DT[, tail(.SD, 3), by=ID]
```

Comment: Actually, when you say "last 3", I bet you mean by date, and it looks like your data aren't sorted by date.  So, you'd need to do that first.  However, that's an awkward format for DATE.

Comment: yes indeed it's last 3 by DATE. the sample was sorted first by ID then by DATE. I'll check data.table immediately. thanks.

Comment: @dmitryungurean, the syntax that the `data.table` package uses takes a little while to get used to, but it's well worth it if you work with big data.  Once you get used to it, I think you'll find it more elegant.  Also, the level of support you'll get from the `data.table` developers (and help docs, vignettes, etc), is top notch.

Comment: Super. Did the job in a couple of minutes. Thanks a lot:)